# I am not able to log in to Stack Exchange using IE10 under Windows 8

Tags: support, status-norepro, login

As soon as I'm on the page where to select the logon provider, I can click on the icons but nothing happens.

With Firefox everything is fine.

What can I do?

Comment: Can't reproduce IE 10 Windows 7 (not saying that it's *not* happening to you). The F12 developer tools might be helpful; attach the script debugger and report any errors, look at network activity to see if a request is initiated and/or aborted, look for errors dumped to the console, etc.

Comment: I've added additional information based on the settings on my system, which also demonstrates this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this on my computer by running IE10 'as administrator'.

The site menus now works again as they used to.

As best as I can tell, the initial error, 'SCRIPT5: Access is denied. full.js, line 109 character 477', appears to have been an issue accessing the local storage.  This has gone away since running IE 'as administrator'.

Comment: Wow. IE needs to run *as administrator* (a HUGE security risk) just to let localstorage work? That's pathetic. (BTW, good answer, +1).

Comment: Ewww. That's madness. Installing Firefox or Chrome and running them _not_ as an administrator seems much, much less dangerous.

Comment: You might want to take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13102116/447356). :)

Comment: I have been able to reproduce this error and was able to solve it by adding http://*.stackoverflow.com/ to the "Trusted Sites" list.

It is *not* necessary, nor is it advisable, to surf the web using IE under elevated privileges (that is, in the "run as Administrator" mode).

Answer (score 2):

I recently had a client that had migrated from IE8 to IE10 and all sorts of issues cropped up on previously working sites with the error : *SCRIPT5: Access is denied*

The issue turned out to be related to Windows profiles as outlined and solved here :

[social.technet.microsoft.com](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/066767a5-f9d5-45f4-95cf-dcd0ff030090/script5-access-is-denied-error-when-accessing-web-sites-using-localstorage?forum=ieitprocurrentver)

> *The integrity setting on the AppData\LocalLow folder in each user's
>   profile is supposed to be set to "Low" (hence the name, presumably).
>   In our case, the integrity level was not set correctly on this folder.
>   To rectify the problem, we will need to run the following command
>   under each user's profile (with a login script, for example):*

```
icacls %userprofile%\Appdata\LocalLow /t /setintegritylevel (OI)(CI)L
```

or :

> *If the command above does not resolve the issue, the registry key that
>   points to the low integrity DOMStore folder may have been changed.
>   Check the CachePath registry value at
>   HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings\5.0\LowCache\Extensible Cache\DOMStore. It should be
>   %USERPROFILE%\AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\DOMStore.*

Answer (score 1):

I just attempted to reproduce this under Windows 8 and IE 10.  It worked just fine.

Comment: Could not reproduce either.

Comment: That link 404s for me

Comment: Apologies about earlier 404; try this: http://www.ntech.ie/public/2013-03-19_11-34-43.mp4

Comment: I'm still not able to reproduce this - do you see any javascript errors in your console?

Comment: F12 IE developer tools reports the following: SCRIPT3: The system cannot find the path specified.
 
openid-jquery.js, line 9 character 73

Comment: Image for the above error
http://i.stack.imgur.com/dQZoS.png

Comment: Do you have any plugins that might be impacting the script execution?

Comment: I have LastPass but disabling it and refreshing the page has no effect when the issue occurs.

Comment: I have this issue as well.  I only noticed it starting on 4/12 or so.  On loading stackoverflow, where initially encountered, the IE console displays 'SCRIPT5: Access is denied.
 
full.js, line 109 character 477' the console then continues with 'SCRIPT12008: WebSocket Error: Incorrect HTTP response. Status code 503, Service Unavailable ', when I leave the console open to stackoverflow.  

Additionally, the links in the 'menu bar' (top of page) work, but the stack exchange and account menus are non-functional.

Windows 7 using IE10.  No addons other than adobe flash, pdf and fiddler.

Comment: When this occurs for me I experience the same issues re stack exchange and account menus also as @OverForkOver