# Issue with login in IE10

Tags: bug, login

I'm wondering if anyone's seen this and got a workaround or fix? Intermittently in IE 10 when on the login page clicking on any of the various icons for the different login methods will not do anything. I have a short (~10 second) video demonstrating this behaviour if you want to see it.

Other browsers (Chrome, FF etc. are fine)

Derek

UPDATE @Mahop seems to have the same issue [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170672/i-am-not-able-to-log-in-to-stack-exchange-using-ie10-under-windows-8) and I am on the same browser/OS mix as him

Comment: You can add a link to your video there then, as a comment (to Geoff's answer perhaps).

Comment: I see the same issue with IE 10/Win 7 but only on *some* stack exchange sites. SO and MSO work fine, but Data SE and a few others I see login issues with; figured it was something funky with the settings in IE so I just stopped using it.

Comment: Do you have any plugin/extension for the browser? Or security software that might be messing with it somehow?

Comment: I have LastPass but disabling it and refreshing the page has no effect when the issue occurs. Video link: http://www.ntech.ie/public/2013-03-19_11-34-43.mp4